# Wordpress Custom Search for Post Type, Meta Key & Taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress

Yesterday I asked this question but I didn't get answer. So I think people don't understand my question. So Here I edit and explain it in details:

My WordPress have a post type Products

I Products have 2 custom field name Color & Location The Products also have enabled Category & Tags Field.

Now my search from look like this:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label>Keyword: </label> <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Keyword"> <br />
    <label>Color: </label> <input type="text" name="color" placeholder="Color"> <br />
    <label>Location: </label> <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location"> <br />
    <label>Category: </label> <select name="category"><option value="1">Shirt</option><option value="1">Pant</option><option value="1">Pajama</option></select> <br />
    <label>Tags: </label> <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Tags"> <br />
    <input type="Submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

So If someone type shirt in keyword field and write Red in color field, then Search Result will show posts by shirt in title & red from meta_key from any category..

If people leave blank keyword field and input Red & Bangladesh in Color & Location field then only posts will come that contain Red & Bangladesh Meta value from any category.

So People can filter search by color, location, category & Tags.

I tried using this kind of search query in search.php but not work.

```
    <?php
        $color = $_GET['color'];
        $location = $_GET['location'];
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'any',
                'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => color,
                        'value' => $color,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => location,
                        'value' => $location,
                    )
            )
         );  
    ?>
      <h3>Your Search For <?php echo $color; ?> <?php if(!empty($location) OR isset($location) OR $location !== NULL ){echo '';} else { echo "and".$location; } ?></h3>

    <?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); if(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post() ?>

                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php if(get_field('color')): ?>
                    <b>Color:</b> <?php the_field('color'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if(get_field('location')): ?>
                    <b>Location:</b> <?php the_field('location'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php else: ?>
        <p class="notice_msg"><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria.'); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Please help me someone. I really need this Help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct is color in `'key' => color,` and location in `'key' => location`, they should be strings like 'color' and 'location' otherwise they will be treated as constants, also add compare parameter in each criteria.

e.g.

```
  <?php
    $color = $_GET['color'];
    $location = $_GET['location'];
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'any',
            'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'color',
                    'value' => $color,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'location',
                    'value' => $location,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
        )
     );  
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I did & its not work. If I blank the Keword field & fill only color or location field.. its come all posts..

Comment: Alright, if the terms are not exact, try `LIKE` in compare criteria instead.

Comment: ok, please comment out both of them for a moment, run a general query and see the exact value of color and location for some posts. later, comment the meta query and use those exact term. In fact, query argument seem totally ok, maybe this is due to AND operator in meta query.

Comment: exact color value is: black  & meta_key is color && location value is: Germany & meta_key is location

Comment: can you fetch the exact sql query by using `echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; after WP_Query()` ?

Comment: where need to use this query ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99523/discussion-between-limexs-and-i-am-stack).